# Android TextView partly gradient

Tags: android, textview, gradient

Android TextView partly gradient,

such as: "hello android hello kotlin", I want "kotlin" gradient, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this programmatically using spannbleSting

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        String fullText = "hello android hello kotlin";
        String gradientText = "kotlin";

        // Find the starting index of the gradient text
        int startIndex = fullText.indexOf(gradientText);

        if (startIndex != -1) {
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(fullText);

            // Define the gradient color and other options
            int[] gradientColors = {0xFF0000FF, 0xFF00FF00}; // Example: Blue to Green
            Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, textView.getTextSize(), gradientColors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

            // Apply the gradient color span to the desired part of the text
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(shader), startIndex, startIndex + gradientText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            textView.setText(spannableString);
        }
    }
    private static class ForegroundColorSpanWithShader extends CharacterStyle implements UpdateAppearance {

    private Shader shader;

    ForegroundColorSpanWithShader(Shader shader) {
        this.shader = shader;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
        tp.setShader(shader);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `ForegroundColorSpan(shader)` no this method

Comment: you can create custom method for that like this
    private static class ForegroundColorSpanWithShader extends CharacterStyle implements UpdateAppearance {

        private Shader shader;

        ForegroundColorSpanWithShader(Shader shader) {
            this.shader = shader;
        }

        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp) {
            tp.setShader(shader);
        }
    }
}

Comment: if the "kotlin" in first line, it's ok, but if the "kotlin" in second line, take no effect

Comment: you can use a static layout to calculate the correct position of the word in textview

Comment: yes, good idea, tks!

Comment: I solved by follow code:

```lang-kotlin
class LinearGradientSpan2(
    private val startColorInt: Int, private val endColorInt: Int, private val rect: Rect
) : CharacterStyle(), UpdateAppearance {

    override fun updateDrawState(tp: TextPaint?) {
        tp ?: return
        tp.shader = LinearGradient(rect.left.toFloat(), rect.top.toFloat(), rect.right.toFloat(), rect.bottom.toFloat(), startColorInt, endColorInt, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)
    }
}

val rect = Rect()
tv.getTextBounds("kotlin",rect)
```